# Como faço para linkar uma imagem no PHP?

Tags: php, html, imagem, link

```
if($formaCombate == "patk")
{
    if($patk1 > $patk2)
    {
        echo "Jogador 1 Ganhou!";
    }
    elseif ($patk1 < $patk2)
    {
         echo "Vitória do jogador 2";
    }
    else
    {       
        echo "<img href='link'><img src='empat1.png'/>";
}
```

Gostaria de *linkar* uma imagem em cada `echo`.

Comment: if($formaCombate == "patk")
{
 if($patk1 > $patk2)
 {
  echo "Jogador 1 Ganhou!";
 }
 elseif ($patk1 < $patk2)
 {
   echo "Vitória do jogador 2";
 }
 else
 {  
  echo "<img href='link'><img src='empat1.png'/>";
}

Comment: Isso aqui está errado `<img href='link'>` ... o certo é algo assim: `<a href='link'><img src='imagem.jpg'/></a>`

Comment: entendi, vou tentar, obrigada

Comment: Deu erro na syntax da ultima linha :(

Comment: Marque a resposta que resolveu seu problema como aceita veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi realmente o que você quer... Acho que você poderia tentar explicar melhor a finalidade ou aceitar uma das respostas abaixo..

Comment: @NathaliaScatena Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

No PHP não tem jeito porque a linguagem não trabalha com isto, mas em HTML tem jeito e está errado no seu código. O PHP é só um agente que está gerando o HTML para você, portanto a questão nada tem a ver com esta linguagem, a não ser que ela seja outra bem diferente do que está descrito.

A *tag* `<a href>` é a que determina que haverá um *link* ali. Ela existe por si só, o que terá dentro pode ser vários elementos do HTML, pode ser um texto ou pode ser uma imagem. HTML são *tags* umas dentro das outras.

```
<a href = 'seu URL aqui'><img src = 'empat1.png'/></a>
```

Se quiser mais legível:

```
<a href = 'seu URL aqui'>
    <img src = 'empat1.png'/>
</a>
```

No caso das outras é só reproduzir este código com o nome da imagem que quer que seja exibida e o devido *link*:

```
if ($formaCombate == "patk") {
    if($patk1 > $patk2) echo "<a href = 'jogador1ganhou.html'><img src = 'venceu1.png'/></a>";
    elseif ($patk1 < $patk2) echo "<a href = 'jogador2ganhou.html'><img src = 'venceu2.png'/></a>";
    else echo "<a href = 'empatou.html'><img src = 'empat1.png'/></a>";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/BuildImageTag.php).

Documentações:

- [`a href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)
- [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Answer (score 2):

Para criar um hiperlink usamos o comando formado pelo par de TAGS `<a> </a>` com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
<a href="destino">texto ou figura ou elemento</a>
```

**Hyperlink de texto** é uma palavra ou frase, que foi atribuída a um URL de destino. Neste caso o visitante do site pode clicar em qualquer lugar da palavra ou frase para exibir seu destino.

exemplo: `<a href="destino">Texto</a>`

**Hyperlink de figura** é uma figura que foi atribuída a um URL de destino. Neste caso, o visitante do site pode clicar em qualquer parte da figura para exibir seu destino.

exemplo: `<a href="destino"><img  src="URL de origem da figura"></a>`

**Na sua aplicação ficaria assim**

```
if($formaCombate == "patk")
{
    if($patk1 > $patk2)
    {
        echo "<a href='link1'>Jogador 1 Ganhou!</a>";
    }
    elseif ($patk1 < $patk2)
    {
         echo "<a href='link2'>Vitória do jogador 2</a>";
    }
    else
    {       
        echo "<a href='link3'><img src='empat1.png'/></a>";
}
```